# Access denied for user 'mysqlRoot'@'iis1.richware.net' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO to connect:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=MYSQL1;dbname=test', mySQLRoot, password);
```

Let me explain my configuration. I have a server named IIS1 which is running IIS7 and MySQL server.

I've just brought up a new server named MYSQL1 which is running MySQL server (only).

My websites are located on IIS1 and I'm trying to connect to the MYSQL server located on MYSQL1. For some reason the PDO class is creating the connection to go to 'iis1.richware.net' as oppose to 'mysql1.richware.net'. My plan is to take down MySQL server on IIS1, but I need to migrate and make sure the new MYSLQ1 server is working okay.

I have the User account on MYSQL1 as:

```
mysqlRoot host: mysql.richware.net Yes ALL PRIVILEGES
```

The User account mysqlRoot does not exist on IIS1.

It seems to me the connection show be made to 'mysqlRoot'@'mysql1.richware.net', but for some reason that is not happening.

Can someone point me to some documentation that explains how I can have two MYSQL servers on the same network and be able to access one or the other depending on which MYSQL server is to be used?

Regards,
Rich

Comment: Did you try to connect via IP instead?

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't work either. the IP for MYSQL1 is 10.10.10.120. Here's the result: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mysqlRoot'@'iis1.richware.net' (using password: YES). It ignored the MySQL:host=10.10.10.120..

Comment: Wait a minute! Yes it did work, however, I had to setup another User account for mysqlRoot where the host was 10.10.10.120. Yes, that did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I did was added the User Account mysqlRoot with host %. Then I was able to connect with:

Host MYSQL1
Username: mysqlRoot
Password: ########

just to test the theory, I added the user account root with host %. I was able to connect with:

Host: MYSQL1
Username: root
Password: ########

Thank you bksi for pointing me to the right direction.